# intel xdk- displaying location markers or nearby shops

Tags: javascript, html, location, intel-xdk

i have the users current location displaying with a red marker. how can i display markers to show shops nearby my location? i've tried to do this in the code below but sadly this is not working. all help is apprenticed. thank-you.

```
var _map = null;
var _seconds = 30;
var _llbounds = null;
var myLatLng;
var oldLatLng = "";
var boolTripTrack = true;
var currentLatitude;
var currentLongitude;

//Create the google Maps and LatLng object 

function drawMap() {
    //Creates a new google maps object
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);
    myLatLng = latlng;
    var mapOptions = {
        center: latlng,
        zoom:7,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
        }
    };
    if (boolTripTrack === true) {
        _map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    }
}

//40.7655,-73.97204 = NYC
//var currentLatitude = "40.713768";
//var currentLongitude = "-73.016696";


var options = {
    timeout: 10000,
    maximumAge: 11000,
    enableHighAccuracy: true
};
//Success callback
var suc = function(p) {
        console.log("geolocation success", 4);
        //Draws the map initially
        if (_map === null) {
            currentLatitude = p.coords.latitude;
            currentLongitude = p.coords.longitude;
            drawMap();
        } else {
            myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.coords.latitude, p.coords.longitude);
        }
        //Creates a new google maps marker object for using with the pins
        if ((myLatLng.toString().localeCompare(oldLatLng.toString())) !== 0) {
            //Create a new map marker
            var Marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatLng,
                map: _map
            });

        }
        oldLatLng = myLatLng;    
    };
var fail = function() {
        console.log("Geolocation failed. \nPlease enable GPS in Settings.", 1);
    };
var getLocation = function() {
        console.log("in getLocation", 4);
    };
    //Execute when the DOM loads  

function onDeviceReady() {
    try {
        if (navigator.geolocation !== null) {
            document.getElementById("map_canvas").style.height = screen.height + "px";
            navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(suc, fail, options);
        }
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e.message);
    }

    try {
        //hide splash screen
        navigator.splashscreen.hide(); 
    } catch (e) {}
}
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);



function click_button_home() {
    window.location.replace('index.html');
}

// this is where i am trying to get different markers to display to show shops nearby the users location

var map;
var infowindow;

function initMap() {
  var pyrmont = {lat: -33.867, lng: 151.195};

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
    center: pyrmont,
    zoom: 15
  });

  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch({
    location: pyrmont,
    radius: 500,
    types: ['store']
  }, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}

function createMarker(place) {
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(place.name);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
  });
}
```